# Merge Excel workbooks to one Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I am trying to merge 250 database excel workbooks into one continuous worksheet.
All of the workbooks have the same kind of data, with the same headers.

I have tried using this VBA code:

```
Sub mergeFiles()
    'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.
    
    'Define variables:
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFileDialog As fileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show
    
    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        
        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
        
        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        
        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        Next tempWorkSheet
        
        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

The code works fine, but it creates a new sheet for every workbook, instead of copying the data to the bottom row of 1 sheet.

Comment: It behaves exactly like the code is designed: `tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)`... You need to take the content of the page and drop it. each time, after the last row with data. I avoided "copying" because it would not be the best method... So, would you like to copy the sheet content starting from its second row up to its last row containing data? All its columns are filled up to the same row? If not, which of them to be consider a reference (the longest)?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is the row limit Excel has per sheet. If you exceed it, you will get an error.

Comment: The workbooks have different amounts of rows. So I have workbooks:
'Fleet A'
With Columns A to G filled with car info like VIN model and so on. Workbooks Fleet A might contain 50 cars (rows) and workbook Fleet B might contain 5000 cars.

I want to combine all the workbooks into one continous file of cars (rows)

Comment: @AndreasKamper: My question was different... Let me rephrase it: In 'Fleet A' all the columns **are filled with data up to the same row**? I mean, **if I calculate the last empty row for column A:A, will that be correct**? Besides that, if your sheet, in your main workbook where the data will be moved, is empty (first time, maybe), the headers will also be copied. And starting from the second file, the range to be moved will start from the second row (except headers) to the last row keeping data (even this one will be different from one file to the other). **Is my understanding correct**?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer starting from those assumptions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a very fast method of data moving (using arrays and working in memory), avoiding Copy and Paste.

1. Copy this new declarations at your declarations area:

   `Dim sh As Worksheet, arrCopy As Variant, lastR As Long`
2. Copy this code line before the loop (`For i = 1 To ...`):

   `Set sh = mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.count) 'You can use here your sheet where the data will be collected. I used the last sheet for easy testing reason`
3. Replace (in the loop `For Each ...`) the existing code (`tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)`) with the next one:

   `lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row`

   `arrCopy = tempWorkSheet.Range(tempWorkSheet.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, 1, 2)), _
             tempWorkSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Value
    sh.Range("A" & lastR + IIf(lastR = 1, 0, 1)).Resize(UBound(arrCopy, 1), _
                                           UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy`

My solution will copy all sheet content (headers included) in case of empty sheet to collect data and after that, data range starting from the second row.

Your full code as it should be in order to work (untested):

```
Sub mergeFiles()
'Define variables:
Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet, arrCopy As Variant, lastR As Long
Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet, lastRtemp As Long

Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True

numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

'You can use here your sheet where the data will be collected. I used the last sheet for easy testing reason
Set sh = mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.count)

    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.count

        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)

        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        Set tempWorkSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
            lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            lastRtemp = tempWorkSheet.Range("A" & tempWorkSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            If lastRtemp < 2 Then
                MsgBox "The workbook " & tempWorkSheet.Name & " contains less the two rows..."
            Else
                arrCopy = tempWorkSheet.Range(tempWorkSheet.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, 1, 2)), _
                  tempWorkSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Value
                sh.Range("A" & lastR + IIf(lastR = 1, 0, 1)).Resize(UBound(arrCopy, 1), _
                                        UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy
            End If

        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208236/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-merge-excel-workbooks-to-one-worksheet).

Answer (score 0):

I used following macro to combine many CSV files in one worksheet in a new workbook.. You may need to make some changes to suit your need

```
Sub GetFromCSVs()
  Dim WB As Workbook
  Dim R As Range
  Dim bFirst As Boolean
  Dim stFile As String
  Dim stPath As String
  stPath = "D:\CSV Files\" ' change the path to suit
  stFile = Dir(stPath & "*.csv")
  'bFirst = True
  Set R = Workbooks.Add(xlWorksheet).Sheets(1).Range("A1")
  Do Until stFile = ""
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(stPath  & stFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    'If bFirst Then
     ' WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=R
      WB.Sheets(1).Range(Selection, Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy Destination:=R
      Set R = R.Offset(R.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1 - R.Row, 0)

      'Set R = Range("A1").Offset(ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row, 0)
      'bFirst = False
    'Else
      'WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(2).Copy Destination:=R
      'Set R = R.Offset(, 1)
    'End If
    WB.Close saveChanges:=False
    stFile = Dir()  ' next file
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I think `Set WB = Workbooks.Open(stPath & stFile, ReadOnly:=True)` should be `Set WB = Workbooks.Open(stFile, ReadOnly:=True)` as stFile is already defined to include stPath

Comment: Also, note that it will copy column headers in sourcesheets. If you dont want them use the commented out if condition `If bFirst Then` after setting bFirst = true before  the loop and changing the loop code

Comment: When i try to run this code, it opens a new sheet, but does not add any data from my database. Am i applying it wrong?

Comment: Check you file extension the code I shared is for  "*.csv"). If your source is excel files the use  `stFile = Dir(stPath & "*.xls*")`

Comment: The files are .csv

Comment: if files are csv then it should at least open first csv file. Then please check stPath. If it is correct then it should open csv file with the code `Set WB = Workbooks.Open(stFile, ReadOnly:=True)`

Comment: the code is working fine at my laptop copying all the rows including header row into a new worksheet....with code 'Set WB = Workbooks.Open(stPath & stFile, ReadOnly:=True)'

Comment: The code provided by FaneDuru solved my issue. But i would like to thank you for contributing Naresh.

Comment: Happy to help. Glad you got a solution